# Eclipse key bindings warnings.

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, keyboard-shortcuts

I've been seeing these warnings reported whenever I am using eclipse autoformat/indentation

```
A conflict occurred for COMMAND+SHIFT+F:
Binding(COMMAND+SHIFT+F,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.jdt.ui.edit.text.java.format,Format,
        Format the selected text,
        Category(org.eclipse.jdt.ui.category.source,Source,Java Source Actions,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@1712f3d,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javaEditorScope,,,system)
Binding(COMMAND+SHIFT+F,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.format.document,Format,
        Format selection,
        Category(org.eclipse.ui.category.edit,Edit,null,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@1f05c08,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.structuredTextEditorScope,,,system)
```

I am not sure to understand why I have this warning ....

I see mutliple such warnings conflicting between org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.format.document and org.eclipse.jdt.ui.edit.text.java.format.

I never installed any keyboard shortcut plugin or some thing.

I am using Eclipse Kepler(4.3) on Mac

Answer (score 0):

looks like there are 2 plugins using the same key binding, the JAva formatter and wst plugin (not sure what it is),

got to `eclipse -> preferences -> general -> keys` and look for which actions are using `COMMAND+SHIFT+F` and unbind the command and it should work